# Openlayers 3 Rotate Multipoint geometry

Tags: rotation, openlayers-3

I'm looking to use a multipoint geometry to hold different points of features I have on my map, but I need to rotate them around a point.

Does Openlayers 3 have any functionality that would allow me to take a Multipoint and rotate it around one of those points?

`ol.coordinates.rotate()` exists but does not perform the action I need.

Is this part of the library or a trigonometry exercise for the implementor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating multiplie `ol.geom.Point` objects and using the following function to rotate them around a given point:-

```
rotateGeometry = function(pointLongitude, pointLatitude, originLongitude, originLatitude, angle) {
    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
    return [Math.cos(angle) * (pointX - originX) - Math.sin(angle) * (pointY - originY) + originX, Math.sin(angle) * (pointX - originX) + Math.cos(angle) * (pointY - originY) + originY];
}
```

Feeding in my coordinates that worked.  An extension of this could be feeding it a multipoint geometry, with a nominated axis point, and rotate all other geometries around it using this function in one go.

Oh, and I had to invert the angle sent in to rotate correctly, but that may be my implementation.

Comments welcomed.